# Can't import under development modules from Canopy IPython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, enthought

I am working on creating a module and having the iPython notebook to work through each usage phase of the module has been really important and i would like to keep using it.

However, I am developing my module from my home directory and the iPython notebook will throw a "no module named XXX" even if it is on sys.path.

I know it is specific to the notebook (Canopy notebook application or notebook specific I'm not sure) as I can import the module just fine in the interpreter.

It was working when I had my module placed in the python site-packages and was just using an rsync to save changes. This got very annoying so I set my PYTHONPATH and everything accordingly but still the notebook resists.

It seems that there must be something else going on.  I'm on Ubuntu 14.4 and python 2.7x.

Comment: Is that directory on sys.path even within the notebook from which you can't import it?

Comment: Yes, the directory is on sys.path upon startup of the notebook. Another difference I noticed was that the notebook adds the directory it is saved in to the sys.path. I moved the ipynb to the module directory and did not help.

Comment: Does this occur when you open the notebook in a browser (after starting `ipython notebook` in a Canopy Terminal session)?

Comment: Yes it is working in the browser. It converted it to the jupyter/v4 as well.

Comment: If it's converted to v3 or higher then you won't be able to reopen it in the Canopy GUI's current notebook anyway, so the issue may be moot, but could you file a bug report from the Canopy Help menu for the record?

Comment: My mentioning version was mostly a side note. So this is a bug? As opposed to a faulty configuration. Do you get similar results in your environment? If you need a module to try it with the project is at https://github.com/salotz/phenomics